# How to provision multiplescope description with single ScopeProvision

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

How can I have provision a single ScopeProvision with multiple description. Currently I am doing like this and there should be a better way

```
       DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc1 = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope("Scope1", serverConnection);
       DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc2 = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope("Scope2 ", serverConnection);
       DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc3 = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope("Scope3", serverConnection);



        SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision1 = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(localConnection, scopeDesc1);
        SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision2 = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(localConnection, scopeDesc2);
        SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision3 = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(localConnection, scopeDesc3);


        clientProvision1.Apply();
        clientProvision2.Apply();
        clientProvision3.Apply();
```

And again while synchronizing we have to create multiple SyncOrchestrator. Cant we avoid this with cleaner once?

Answer (score 1):

you cant. a Scope Description defines what a scope is. a scope cant have multiple definitions.

if you want them under one scope, then you should include all the tables in one scope.